# Typescript underscore case translation

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using my domain class like this:

```
export class Contact {

  private _name: string;
  private _phone: string;

  get name(): string {
    return this._name;
  }

  set name(value: string) {
    this._name = value;
  }

  get phone(): string {
    return this._phone;
  }

  set phone(value: string) {
    this._phone = value;
  }

}
```

My problem is when I send data to backend through angular http.post, the properties that are sent are the those with underscore and my backend is prepared only for camelCase (Change backend might not be an option here). Is there any other known option besides translate JSON before send?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two ways to do that:

1) Defining a `toJSON()` function on your `Contact` class:

```
public toJSON() {
    return {
        name: this._name,
        phone: this._phone,
    };
}
```

2) By using `JSON.stringify(...)`, replacing the 2nd argument:

```
let serialized = JSON.stringify(contact, Object.keys(contact.constructor.prototype))
```

> To know more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify